# Creating a List Column with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jsom

I am trying to create a column in a list in SharePoint 2013 but I receive the following error.  Anybody know what it means.

**Request failed. 'FirstName' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 32.
undefined**

```
    function addFields(NewField) {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    //Getting reference to the list
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Departmental Square Feet');
    console.log("Got the list");
    // Get filed collection
    var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

    var f1 = clientContext.castTo(fldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Text" DisplayName='+NewField+' Name='+NewField+' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType), SP.FieldText);
    console.log("About to set the field");
    f1.set_title(NewField);
    f1.set_description("sample desc");
    console.log("About to update");
    f1.update();       


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("List Field Updated");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

addFields("FirstName");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Solved**, I have tried running your code in my test environment and found the issue. It was arising due to improper formation of String when defining your field as XML. The Error  says you should have provided the field's DisplayName and Name in double quotes. viz:

```
'<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="+NewField+" Name="+NewField+" />'
```

**Below is the Complete test code and screen shot:**

```
<input type="button" value="No SPS" onClick="addFields();" style="color:black; background-color:grey" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function addFields() {
    var NewField = "FirstName";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    //Getting reference to the list
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
    console.log("Got the list");
    // Get filed collection
    var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

    var f1 = clientContext.castTo(fldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="+NewField+" Name="+NewField+" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType), SP.FieldText);
    console.log("About to set the field");
    f1.set_title(NewField);
    f1.set_description("sample desc");
    console.log("About to update");
    f1.update();       


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("List Field Updated");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

[image]