# On to Create Sharepoint 2013 List columns Using JSOM / REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have a list of column names(64 columns) which needs to be created in SharePoint 2013 Custom List.

When a new list is created these 64 columns needs to created through JSOM or Rest API on one go. Any suggested ways or code can help me on this.

Thank you so much !!

-Dhana

Comment: Create a content type with that 64 columns, and create a SharePoint custom list from that content type. Instead of creating columns repetitively. Or else we can have site columns if you don't want data. Do you need to create these columns through JSOM only?

Comment: try this column creation with the JSOM [Creating column with JSOM ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219522/creating-a-list-column-with-jsom)

Answer (score 0):

You could add all field Json data in data for Rest API Ajax call like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
PostCreateByREST = function (restUrl, data) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        url: restUrl,
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
            result = true;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

var dataFieldCreation = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'FieldTypeKind': 2, 'Title':'testfield'}";
var success = PostCreateByREST("http://sp/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Dummy')/fields", dataFieldCreation);

</script>
```